# Microsoft List - formatting every second row with a diffrent color

Tags: sharepoint-list

i would like to formatt my Microsoft List as follow:

I would like to color every second row gray and in addition, when a status is set to Completed, set the complete row to green.

Can someone help me with the JSON Code?

Thanks.

Greetings
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON like below for your SharePoint JSON view formatting settings:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Status]=='Completed','sp-field-severity--good',if(@rowIndex%2==0,'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgLightGray30','sp-css-backgroundColor-noFill'))"
}
```

Where `Status` is the **internal name** of your SharePoint list column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

**Steps to add JSON**:

1. Choose Format current view option from your list view like:

   [image]
2. Switch to **Advanced mode**
3. Add above JSON in text box and click Save button